# Parallel curl with file input and output filename on Linux shell

Tags: curl, gnu-parallel

I usually download files on parallel with curl and urls in a file like this:

```
cat links.txt | parallel --will-cite curl --connect-timeout 5 --max-time 10 --retry-max-time 40 --retry 5 --retry-delay 0 -s -f -O -C -
```

Where links.txt has one url per line.

Now I need to assign a custom filename to each file and I can't figure out how to add this second input to `curl` trough `parallel`. Among other things, I tried to add `-o  filename` to each line of `links.txt` but it didn't work.

Regards,

Comment: Show us how you would do it if you had to do 3 "by hand" (i.e. without using GNU Parallel). (And consider running `parallel --bibtex` once).

Comment: copy-paste and change url an filename of this: `curl --connect-timeout 5 --max-time 10 --retry-max-time 40 --retry 5 --retry-delay 0 -s -f -C - -o filename1 url1`

Comment: Do you really want all urls saved into `filename1`?

Comment: nop. copy-paste means `curl ... filename1 url1`, `curl ... filename2 url2                       `, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `man parallel`, you can use some placeholders to aid you. For example, you could rewrite your code to:

```
parallel curl "${CURL_ARGS[@]}" -o '{#}'.curl_output '{}' :::: links.txt
```

where `${CURL_ARGS[@]}` are all your arguments to `curl` and `links.txt` has one URL per line. This command you fetch the URLs in `links.txt` and will store the result in a file named after the number of the job than run curl (e.g., `10.curl_output`). You would have to march job number with URLs.

Another approach would be to call `curl` with `-o '{}'._curl_output`. In this case, you would have to deal with special characters in URLs (`/`, for example).

Besides those, you could also split the columns on a `links.txt` which contains an URL and an output file per line. This would let you do

```
parallel --colsep " " curl "${CURL_ARGS[@]}" -o '{1}' '{2}' :::: links.txt
```

The `--colsep` will split the lines based on the delimiter provide as its argument (`" "` in this case).

Comment: Thanks! Your third option was exactly what I was looking for. Nevertheless, the other options can be useful in other situations...